# angular-toastr preventOpenDuplicates is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-toastr

I am using [angular-toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) and trying to prevent duplicate toastr by using toastr option `preventOpenDuplicates`, but might be its not working or may be I am doing something wrong.

[plunkr to reproduce issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/qyqMfZTfcMBwQLUwW322?p=preview)

toastr :

```
toastr.error('test', 'open duplicate', {
  closeButton: true,
  tmeOut: 0,
  preventOpenDuplicates:true,
  progressBar: true
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you tell `angular-toastr` to not show duplicate is by setting `preventDuplicates` to `true` inside the `toastrConfig` object. And not in the `toastr.error` or `success` or any opener for that matter.

So, your code would look something like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, toastr, toastrConfig) {

  toastrConfig.preventDuplicates = true;
  toastrConfig.preventOpenDuplicates = true;
  toastrConfig.progressBar = true;
  toastrConfig.closeButton = true;
  
  $scope.OpenToastr = function() {
    toastr.error('test', 'open duplicate');
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: Found it! It's the version! :)

According to [`angular-toastr > CHANGELOG`](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-140),

> ## Version 1.4.0
>
> - With `preventOpenDuplicates` you can prevent duplicates of opened toasts.

The functionality got introduced in `1.4.0` and you were using `1.3.1`.

[**working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/R0yrlKhIxvxBBXw4YpmU?p=preview) (updated)

Comment: preventDuplicates is working fine after set in toastrConfig, but its not open same toastr again after closed.

Comment: `preventOpenDuplicates` is usefull in my case, but its not working, let me update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng7-snack-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng7-snack-bar). It helps to prevent duplicates and auto closes on transition.